# Add extra fields to Jersey responses

Tags: jackson, jersey

Using Jackson and Jersey, I want to add some extra fields to the response body sent back to the client.
I am using strongly typed objects and build responses like this:

```
 // ...
 return Response.status(200).entity(myTypebObject).build();
```

I want to manipulate outbound responses and add the same fields to every single response.
I won't know the values of these fields until after I make the typedObject.  I had considered using Jersey response filter but the problem with that is, I may need to hit the database again to get the values for the extra fields so the outbound filter doesn't sound right.

Writing a custom deserialiser also seems over kill.  If I could just get the fields and then literally create a new object and merge the contents of myTypebObject all would be good.  Any tips appreciated.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a purpose why [WriterInterceptor](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html), has been created.

Comment: You can use a response filter. Get the object from the response context and cast it, then set the values.You can also use name binding annotations to have the filter used only on specific resources.